# Distributed database implementation in sql server

Tags: sql-server, distributed-database

Currently, We have central Database at Head Office and users from sub offices ,scattered around the country, connect to central database.
Now we want to distribute the database in disconnected mode at each Sub office level and we want data to be synchronized at the day end at the central Database from all others Databases. We also want transfer of data to all Databases from central Database.
Please refer me the tutorial or way to implement this scenario in SQL Server.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/